# Whole body resizes when resizing window....why?

Tags: resize

I understand that anything nested in a parent div will inherit the properties of the parent, but I still cannot figure this out. I like how everything is laid out, as is. but when I resize my window, everything that was centered gets pushed right if I slide the right side of the browser toward the left. I've made other web pages. I can't see what I am doing wrong. Ideas? I included some of the css below. I did not include the html because its not an object moving....its the whole body.

```
body {
background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat left top;
color: #78394e;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 12px;
min-width: 960px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
border-width: 3px; 
border-style: dotted; 
border-color: teal; 
}

#header {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If i understand you correctly, when you resize your browser, your body width will be still '100%'. I figure your centered content's style doesn't have a fixed width defined. Am I correct?

Comment: It does not. It has a percentage. Could that be why?

Comment: as a test, I changed the percentage to an actual amount and now it shifted the whole body over "on its own". Strange. Now I am thinking, what is causing it to be "shifted" to the right in the first place...

Comment: figured it out. I had to set the div to an actual amount and then position it. When re-sizing, it didn't move. Thanks for the idea!!!

Comment: Lol.. auto solved.. glad u got it working.. cheers..